# I can't find the nth power of a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

i have the following matrix : $$A=\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -4   \\
2 & -5    \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$
and i have to find  $A^n$ . I calculated $A^2=\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
-7 & 16   \\
-8 & 17    \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$ , $A^3=\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
25 & -52   \\
26 & -53    \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$ , $A^4=\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
-79 & 160   \\
-80 & 161    \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$ However i cannot find a pattern between them . Can you help me ? Thank you .

Comment: Have you heard of the eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: Your matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $-1$ and $-3$. So it works exactly as in the duplicate.

Comment: Your matrix has distinct eigenvalues; therefore, it is diagonalizable. The matrix can be decomposed as $A=PDP^{-1}$ where 
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix} -3&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}, P = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}, P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -1&2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Finally $A^{n}=PD^{n}P^{-1}$, or 
$$
A^n = P \begin{bmatrix} -3^n&0\\0&-1^n\end{bmatrix} P^{-1}.
$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didn't like the answers in the duplicate. They are loquacious.